# The below code is giving a nested tuple. from which i want a list of tuples to pass them into a function

Tags: python-3.x

```
S=[(5,7),(2,9),(3,8),(1,4),(6,2)]
p=(4,3)
q={S[i]:p for i in range(len(S))}
list2=list(q.items())
print(list2)
```

result is... [((5, 7), (4, 3)), ((2, 9), (4, 3)), ((3, 8), (4, 3)), ((1, 4), (4, 3)), ((6, 2), (4, 3))]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the results to be displayed as so:

```
[(5, 7), (4, 3), (2, 9), (4, 3), (3, 8), (4, 3), (1, 4), (4, 3), (6, 2), (4, 3)]
```

For this you can just do:

```
>>>list_tuple = [item for a in list2 for item in a]
>>>print(list_tuple)
[(5, 7), (4, 3), (2, 9), (4, 3), (3, 8), (4, 3), (1, 4), (4, 3), (6, 2), (4, 3)]
```